# PHP preg replace help

Tags: php, preg-replace

HI, I have these strings:

`#05#, #45#, #785#` ...etc

I need to get the id so #01544# become 01544. How can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
preg_replace('(#([0-9]+)#)', '\1', '#05#, #45#, #785#');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
echo str_replace("#", "", "#05#, #45#, #785#");
```

more info at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$str = trim('#01544#', '#');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `str_replace`? E.g.

```
$string = str_replace('#', '', $string);
```

For simple patterns like this, regex is never necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `str_replace`:

```
$id = str_replace("#", "", $your_variable);
```